# Wie kann man "Bohrungen am Bestand und an neuen Profilen" oder "Bohrungen am Bestand und am neuen Profil" kürzer sagen?

Tags: adjective, inflection

Kann man statt

> Bohrungen am Bestand und an neuen Profilen

eines von

> Bohrungen am Bestand und neuen Profilen
> Bohrungen an Bestand und neuen Profilen

schreiben? Ist es überhaupt möglich? Und wie sieht es im Singular aus? Also statt

> Bohrung am Bestand und am neuen Profil

eines von

> Bohrung am Bestand und neuem Profil
> Bohrung an Bestand und neuem Profil

"Am" passt zwar nicht zu "neuem", steht aber nicht direkt davor, vielleicht geht's ja dann.
Funktioniert die zweite Variante überhaupt?

Mich würde weiters interessieren, ob das ein ausschließlich grammatikalisches "Problem" ist, oder ob die Bedeutung der jeweiligen Wörter entscheidet, ob man [am Adjektiv+en] mit [an Adjektiv+em] ersetzen kann.

Kontext: Es geht um eine Symbolbeschreibung auf einem Plan. Das Symbol kennzeichnet Bohrungen an Bestandsprofilen und Bohrungen an neuen Profilen. Aufgrund von Platzmangel wäre es aber super, wenn man das abkürzen könnte, zB so wie oben vorgeschlagen. Doch ist es auch wichtig, dass die Kurzversion grammatikalisch richtig, sofern es überhaupt eine gibt.

Comment: Keine Ahnung, ob es eine Regel gibt, aber ich denke, in diesem Kontext ist die Grammatik nicht ganz so wichtig, solange es für den vorgesehenen Personenkreis verständlich ist und sich nicht völlig falsch anhört. Je nachdem, ob man *Bestand* für sich allein oder als Verkürzung von Bestandsprofilen betrachtet, könnte man unterschiedliche Varianten wählen. Weitere Möglichkeit: "Bohrungen an Bestands- und neuen Profilen". Könnte es statt "neue Profile" auch "Neubau", "Neuteile" o.ä. heißen?

Comment: @Bodo Da hast du vollkommen recht, es geht mir ohnehin mehr um mein Verständnis. Montagebohrung Bestand+neues Profil zeichnet sich eh schon ab :P
Der Bestand umfasst nicht unbedingt nur Profile. Neubau gefällt mir gut (trotz der dominanten Bedeutung als "nicht Altbau" aus dem Hochbau) werde das vorschlagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"an" oder "am"?

Wir kennen den Kontext nicht, aber meistens finden wir hier die Kontraktion zu "am" - Entweder, weil "Haus" generisch benutzt wird, oder weil das spezifische Haus beiden Gesprächspartnern bekannt ist. (Dudenband 4 Nr. 925).

> Die Bohrung **am** [Haus].
> Die Bohrung **an dem** [Haus].

Die Reihung mit der Konjunktion erlaubt uns, keinen Artikel zu verwerden - wodurch auch ausnahmsweise *im Singular* einfach nur *an* genutzt werden darf.

> Die Bohrung **an** [Haus und Hof].

Natürlich wissen wir nun nicht mehr, ob *an* den Dativ oder den Akkusativ regiert - vom Kontext bzw. der Bedeutung des Verbs ergibt aber nur die Interpretation als Dativ Sinn - denn *in Richtung Haus und Hof bohren* ist Unsinn.

Dudenband 4, Randnummer 391

---

**Regel**:

- Präpositionen gleich -> Eine kann weggelassen werden.
- Präpositionen ungleich *oder* Präpositionen gleich, aber eine ist eine Kontraktion -> Weglassen sollte vermieden werden.

Bei *an* ... *an* lässt sich die zweite Präposition problemlos weglassen. (Duden 4 Nr. 1422)

Bei *am* ... *an* ist es die Entscheidung schwieriger. Schließich ist *Bestand* Singular und *Profile* im Plural, wodurch sich das erste *an* mit dem Artikel verbindet.
Erwähnt wird das im Dudenband bei Randnummer 1423.
Laut dem Duden wird hier die Auslassung **vermieden**.

Stehen beide im Singular, ist es wiederum möglich, da beide die Kontraktion "am" nutzen können.

Folglich zusammenfassend ist richtig:

Singular

> ... am Bestand und am neuen Profil.
> ... am Bestand und (am) neue**n** Profil.
> ... an Bestand und (an) neue**m** Profil.  (Reihung erlaubt Artikellosigkeit).

Ohne Kontraktion (am = an dem) im Singular:

> ... an dem Bestand und an dem neuen Profil.
> ... an dem Bestand und (an dem) neuen Profil.

Plural

> ... an Beständen und an neuen Profilen.
> ... an Beständen und (an) neuen Profilen.

Singular + Plural

> ... am Bestand und an neuen Profilen.
> **Vermeiden**: ... am Bestand und (an) neuen Profilen.

Plural + Singular

> ... an Beständen und am neuen Profil.
> **Vermeiden**: ... an Beständen und (am) neuen Profil.

Comment: Vielen Dank, das hilft mir schon viel weiter! Aber "neu" gehört nur zu Profil, der Bestand ist nicht neu (sondern eben die schon vorhandene Konstruktion).
Was genau meinst du mit "unterscheiden sich die grammatischen Merkmale"?

Comment: @KarloGrba Damit meine ich einfach nur, dass das eine Wort Singular und das andere Plural ist. Das führt hier zu verschiedenen Adjektivformen, wieso man sie nicht zusammenfassen kann. Da es aber gar nicht um eine Zusammenfassung geht, ist das natürlich egal.

Comment: @KarloGrba Ich habe die Frage nun richtig beantwortet, und entsprechende irrelevante Dinge aus der Antwort entfernt.

Comment: Und wenn Profil im Singular steht?

Comment: @KarloGrba Dann ist die Auslassung wieder möglich, weil beide Präpositionen dieselben sind.

Comment: @KarloGrba "am Bestand und am neuen Profil". Zwei mal "am" heißt, ein "am" kann weggelassen werden. 
Wenn Sie aber "am" und "an" nutzen wollen, dann sollten Sie das lieber vermeiden. Verboten ist das (laut der Dudengrammatik) allerdings nicht, nur vermieden.

Comment: @KarloGrba Ich habe eine Übersicht hinzugefügt, wo verschiedene Ausdrucksweisen. die empfohlen werden, aufgelistet sind. Hoffentlich hilft es.

Answer (score 1):

Kürzer?

> Bestands- und Neuprofilbohrungen

Noch kürzer?

> Bestands- u. Neuprofilbohrungen

Noch kürzer?

> Bestands-/Neuprofilbohrung[en]

Comment: Hmm, Neuprofil ist nicht wirklich gebräuchlich, aber mal ein frischer Zugang.

Answer (score 1):

**Update und Hinweis**:

Wegen des fehlenden Kontextes war ich gedanklich mit meiner Antwort im falschen Fachbereich unterwegs. Nach den Kommentaren von Karlo Grba sind wohl technische und nicht geologische Profile bzw. Bohrungen gemeint.

---

Technisch gesehen nützt ein einzelnes Symbol in der Legende eines z.B. geologischen Plans für zwei zu unterscheidende Profilbohrungen wenig. Eine visuelle Unterscheidung ist bei einem Einzelsymbol nur mit Farbe möglich, die dann aber auch in der Legende mit zwei Farben getrennt zu beschreiben ist.

In einem Plan werden meist mehrere Bohrungen mit der Symbolik dargestellt. Der Plural ist aber in der zugehörigen Legende nicht zu benutzen. Der Betrachter findet in einer Landkarte zum Beispiel **♁** und in der Legende dazu im Singular **Kirche**.

Man bohrt auch nicht `am` sondern **im Bestand** der bereits vorhandenen Bohrungen aus denen sich die Profile ableiten.

Eine Bohrung wird nicht gleichzeitig im Bestandsprofil und für eine neues Profil niedergebracht werden - daher schlage ich bei einem einzelnen Symbol ein **oder** vor.

Für zwei getrennte Symbole:

- **Bohrung im Bestandsprofil** oder besser **Bohrung (Bestandsprofil)**
- **Bohrung für neues Profil** oder besser **Bohrung (Neues Profil)**

Für ein einzelnes Symbol:

- **Bohrung im Bestands- oder neuen Profil**

Comment: Die mit diesem Symbol gekennzeichneten Bohrungen sollen sich auch nicht voneinander unterscheiden, sondern von jenen, welche schon im Werk gebohrt wurden (im Gegensatz zu diesen, welche vor Ort gebohrt werden müssen). Der Zusatz "vor Ort" war für die Frage zur Grammatik mE irrelevant, sie sind aber in diesem Sinne gleich.  

>Man bohrt auch nicht am sondern im Bestand der bereits vorhandenen Bohrungen aus denen sich die Profile ableiten.  
Dass die Präposition überhaupt falsch sein könnte, ist mir noch gar nicht in den Sinn gekommen, aber den Rest vom Satz verstehe ich nicht ganz.

Comment: Es gibt immer einen Bestand (welcher keine Profile umfassen muss), und ein oder mehrere neue Profile, welche draufgeschraubt werden sollen. Die Bohrung erfolgt in diesem Fall (bei diesem Symbol) immer an beidem, man kann sich's also nicht aussuchen. Die "neue" Frage wäre also, ob man "Bohrung im Bestand und neuen Profil" oder "Bohrung in Bestand und neuem Profil" sagen kann. Wenn nicht, wird's wohl Arial Narrow.

Comment: Aus welchem Fachberich kommt diese Konversation?

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana - wegen des fehlenden Kontextes war ich gedanklich im falschen Fachbereich unterwegs. Nach den Kommentaren von Karlo Grba sind wohl technische und nicht geologische Profile bzw. Bohrungen gemeint.